# Can I not change a list inside a function?

Tags: python, list

```
# left rotate using slicing
def leftRotate(arr, k, n):
    arr = arr[k:] + arr[:k]
    print(arr)

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 
leftRotate(arr, 2, 7) 
print(arr)
```

Result:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

When I print the array outside the function it is not rotated anymore and remains how it originally was. Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: yes you can, but you aren't modifying the list in your function, you simply assign to a local variable `arr` and then the function terminates

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can change a list from within a function, but you need to use the correct syntax.  As you've seen already, this is not the correct way:

```
def leftRotate(arr, k, n):
    arr = arr[k:] + arr[:k]
```

I will try to explain why this did not work, and hope to give you a better intuition about what really happens.  Inside the scope of the function shown above, there are 3 local variables: `arr`, `k`, and `n`.  The right-hand side operations `arr[k:] + arr[:k]` creates a new list object, without modifying the original list, and this resulting object is bound to the local variable name  `arr`.  This does not modify the original object, because such assignment statements in Python are *never* mutating objects. They will only bind a name in a namespace. **Think of it as if you're taking the nametag "arr" off of the old list object**, which was passed in as argument, **and sticking it on the new list object** which was just created. The old list object is not modified by such an operation, only the local namespace is modified - the old list object becomes "anonymous" and is no longer reachable in this scope.

The solution is to use a different kind of assignment statement, a *slice assignment*, which does mutate:

```
def leftRotate(arr, k, n):
    arr[:] = arr[k:] + arr[:k]
```

As a final note, there is a list-like data structure in stdlib which provides more efficient rotation operations (at the cost of less-efficient indexing into the middle of the collection). If you're interested in this,  read the docs on the [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque).

Comment: Thats is very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The problem is list slicing is *not* being applied in place. Effectively a *new* list is created and assigned to a variable `arr` scoped to `leftRotate`, i.e. it can can be accessed within your function only. A method which does work in place *will* work as expected:

```
def rev_sort(arr, k, n):
    arr.sort(reverse=True)
    print(arr)

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 
rev_sort(arr, 2, 7) 

print(arr)

[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

In your example, you can have your function return a list and assign it to `arr`:

```
def leftRotate(arr, k, n):
    arr = arr[k:]+arr[:k]
    print(arr)
    return arr

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 
arr = leftRotate(arr, 2, 7) 
print(arr)

[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Slice assignment will modify `arr` in place, without requiring the return+assignment.

Comment: @PaulMcG, Indeed, that's true. As per wim's solution (which is a great alternative if OP doesn't want to return `arr`).

Comment: That's helpful. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is because you can't change a variable inside a python function because of the scope. [Read this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) for more info.

But resuming, you need to either return arr and assign it outside. Like this:

```
#left rotate using slicing
def leftRotate(arr, k, n):
    arr=arr[k:]+arr[:k]
    return arr

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 
arr = leftRotate(arr, 2, 7) 
print arr
```

Or if you would like, you could make arr a global. (Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function) for more info on that). (Don't recommend this last one, but exists)

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

#left rotate using slicing
def leftRotate( k, n):
    global arr
    arr=arr[k:]+arr[:k]

leftRotate( 2, 7) 
print arr
```

Hope it helped :)

Comment: Helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score -5):

There are a lot of really complicated answers. Here's the "for dummies" version:

- You are passing `arr` into `leftRotate()`
- For nearly all purposes, you can think of this as creating *another variable*, also called `arr` which `leftRotate()` works on. `leftRotate()`'s `arr` is **not the same** as the `arr` you are passing in to `leftRotate()`. It **is a copy** (technically it's not a copy until you assign `arr` to something else, but close enough for these purposes).
- You're not getting your modified `arr` back out of `leftRotate()` again.

You can solve this in two ways:

- Define `arr` outside of `leftRotate()`, and don't pass `arr` in. I'll call this the "`global`" approach. Not recommended unless you have a *very* good reason.
- Use `return arr` after your function completes. Essentially, `return 'x'` means `leftRotate() == 'x'`. In 99.99999% of cases, this is what you want.

Therefore, in your example, what you really want is this:

```
#left rotate using slicing
def leftRotate(arr, k, n):
    arr=arr[k:]+arr[:k] # not sure this is right, but once you get the return working, it should be easy to debug
    # print arr # changed
    return arr

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 
# leftRotate(arr, 2, 7) # changed
arr = leftRotate(arr, 2, 7) 
print arr
```

Comment: Are you sure that passing `arr` into `leftRotate` creates a copy?

Comment: Your assumption that `arr` passed to the function is a copy is incorrect. The part that fails is that assignment to `arr` inside the function just assigns to a new, local name, not affecting the original `arr`. It *is* possible to update the original passed-in `arr` by using slice assignment, as shown in @wim 's answer.

Comment: I said it was the &quot;for dummies&quot; version. That means it's meant to be more easily understandable, if not precisely correct. We're not all professional coders (and OP prob isn't). I can tell you it's not a pointer/assignment. "Copy" to most people is the same as "local variable outside of scope" or whatever.